# Cannot access Amazon EC2 instance after changing sshd_config file (deadlock)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was trying to access Amazon EC2 instance without using keypairs (I was doing some tests with Dreamweaver)
So, I had a marvelous ideia of changing sshd_config file.

> sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

And I change the PasswordAuthentication line to:

> Match User ubuntu
>
> > ```
> >  PasswordAuthentication yes
> > ```

After restarting I got a sad surprise. I cannot access my machine anymore. And even worst I had only one user (ubuntu) on this instance.

My question is:

How can I back to original setting ( roolback sshd_config file) if I cannot access my terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Loosing access to an [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance is a common encounter - how to approach this situation when you don't know the reason yet is addressed in Eric Hammond's excellent summary [Solving: "I can't connect to my server on Amazon EC2"](http://alestic.com/2009/08/ec2-connectivity).

However, since you already now that the problem is permission related, you can apply his respective instructions [Fixing Files on the Root EBS Volume of an EC2 Instance](http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-fix-ebs-root) right away, see my answer to the related question [Fixing Amazon EC2 Permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/365587/fixing-amazon-ec2-permissions) for a short summary of this approach.

Good luck!